# Invalid procedure call or argument: 'Mid'

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have a function (see below) and it works perfectly. I recently moved my code to another server and i did not change anything in it. It fails to run on new server.

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0005'
Invalid procedure call or argument: 'Mid'
/calculate.asp, line 416
```

When i checked the line 416, i got this:

```
Dim result3: result3 = Mid(o3.responseText, Basla3, Bitir3)
```

and this is the complete function:

```
<%
    Function xyz()
    Dim o3: Set o3 = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    Dim o_date3: o_date3 = split(EndingDate, ".")
    Dim s_date3
    If (Len(o_date3(2)) = 4) Then
        s_date3 = o_date3(2)
    Else
        s_date3 = "20" & o_date3(2)
    End If
    If (Len(o_date3(1)) = 2) Then
        s_date3 = s_date3 & o_date3(1)
    Else
        s_date3 = s_date3 & "0" & o_date3(1)
    End If
    If (Len(o_date3(0)) = 2) Then
        s_date3 = s_date3 & o_date3(0)
    Else
        s_date3 = s_date3 & "0" & o_date3(0)
    End If
    Dim s3: s3 = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""         xmlns:urn=""urn:AntTransferWSIntf-IAntTransferWS""><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><urn:EURCurrency soapenv:encodingStyle=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/""><DateStr xsi:type=""xsd:string"">" + s_date3 + "</DateStr></urn:EURCurrency></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>"
    o3.Open "POST", serviceUrl, False
    o3.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    o3.setRequestHeader "Connection", "close"
    o3.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", " "
    o3.send s3
    Dim hataVarMiBasla3: hataVarMiBasla3 = (InStr(1, o3.responseText, "<faultstring>", vbTextCompare)) + 13
    If (hataVarMiBasla3 > 13) Then
        Dim hataVarMiBitir3: hataVarMiBitir3 = (InStr(1, o3.responseText, "</faultstring>", vbTextCompare)) - hataVarMiBasla3
        Dim hata3: hata3 = Mid(o3.responseText, hataVarMiBasla3, hataVarMiBitir3)
        KurGetir = hata3
    Else
        Dim Basla3: Basla3 = (InStr(1, o3.responseText, """xsd:double"">", vbTextCompare)) + 13
        Dim Bitir3: Bitir3 = (InStr(1, o3.responseText, "</return>", vbTextCompare)) - Basla3
        Dim result3: result3 = Mid(o3.responseText, Basla3, Bitir3)
        xyz = CDbl(Replace(result3, ".", mstrComma))
    End If
    Set o3 = Nothing
End Function
%>
```

Why am i receiving this error?

Comment: Check the validity of the `Mid` parameters values.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what do you mean by that?

Comment: you should check the values which you are passing in Mid function I.E.  o3.responseText , hataVarMiBasla3, hataVarMiBitir3 , Basla3, Bitir3

Answer (score 5):

[Mid struct from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wffts6k3%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

> Mid(string, start[, length])

Not official reference but according to my experience, you get that error if

1. **start** is less than or equal to zero.
2. **length** is less than zero (if it is not missed in the Mid call)

Have a look at the error line and related ones.

```
Dim Basla3: Basla3 = (InStr(1, o3.responseText, """xsd:double"">", vbTextCompare)) + 13
Dim Bitir3: Bitir3 = (InStr(1, o3.responseText, "</return>", vbTextCompare)) - Basla3
Dim result3: result3 = Mid(o3.responseText, Basla3, Bitir3)
```

Lets suppose `o3.responseText` is empty because your code does not check whether the response is empty.
`Basla3` can not be less than 13 according to `InStr() + 13`, so it's not the problem.
However it seems like `Bitir3` can be less then zero according to `InStr() - Basla3` (Basla3 evaluated as 13). 
Continuing with the assumption, `(InStr(1, o3.responseText, "</return>", vbTextCompare))` evaluated as `0`, then with `- Basla3` it will be evaluated as `-13`. 
Tada! **rule 2** violated, *length cannot be less than zero*.

The problem with your code is, there is no check response length nor response status.
If the response is empty, consider the following:

1. Your new server may have connectivity problems unlike the old one.
2. The API which you have is authorized for the old server's IP address only.

In a nutshell, you should optimize the code and be sure that there is an xml response. 
At least use something like that:

```
o3.Send
If o3.readyState = 4 And o3.status = 200 Then
    If Len(o3.responseText) > 0 Then
        'response is ready to parse
    Else
        'response status is ok but empty
    End If
Else
    'request failed
End If
```

BTW, due to your request is a soap call, I'd highly recommend done the job by parsing xml response using DomDocument etc. 
Replacing decimal points, using `Mid & InStr` pair to check node existence are just trouble and bad practice also.

Answer (score 4):

If I were to take a guess.

VBScript gives strange errors when your "MID" function has to deal with special characters, or what it thinks are non-string values.

So, o3.responseText probably contains text that it doesn't like.

Comment: Again, I would guess that your two servers are not configured the same, their web folder structure for instance. Also: can you post the actual values for the 3 variables.